# Read json with null list into data.frame

Tags: r, json

I am trying to load a json file into a data.frame in r. But there is some `named list()` which is null in my json data.

Here is my json data:

```
json_file1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{"txtId":"20180101","data":{"user":[{"id":"123","phone":"00001","realName":"Eric","addr":{},"source":{},"registerDate":{},"type":0,"remain":{}}],"score":[], "live_city":"Nice","live_county":"France"}}')
json_file2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{"txtId":"20180102","data":{"user":[{"id":"456","phone":"00002","realName":"Amy","addr":{},"source":{},"registerDate":{},"type":0,"remain":100}],"score":[], "live_city":{},"live_county":{}}}')
json_file = list(json_file1, json_file2)
zt.detail = lapply(json_file, function(y){
  if(!is.null(y$data)) data.frame(y$data, stringsAsFactors = F)
})
```

when I rbind zt.detail, I get the error:

```
# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
#                       arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

So I want to transfer those `list()` or `named list()` into NA before and rbind those data then get the following result:

```
id phone realName type remain addr source registerDate live_city live_county
123 00001  Eric    0    NA     NA     NA    NA            Nice     France  
456 00002  Amy     0    100    NA     NA    NA             NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recursive function for the nested JSON object. The rbind function part could be made as a for loop if there are many JSON files.

```
ff <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x) && length(x) > 0) lapply(x, ff)
  else if (is.list(x) && length(x) == 0) 'NA'
  else x
  }

output1 <- ff(json_file1$data)
output2 <- ff(json_file2$data)

X <- rbind(data.frame(output1, stringsAsFactors = F), data.frame(output2, stringsAsFactors = F))
```

Modify column names:

```
colnames(X) <- c('id', 'phone', 'realName', 'addr', 'source', 'registerDate', 'type', 'remain', 'score', 'live_city', 'live_county')

X

   id phone realName addr source registerDate type remain score live_city live_county
1 123 00001     Eric   NA     NA           NA    0     NA    NA      Nice      France
2 456 00002      Amy   NA     NA           NA    0    100    NA        NA          NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a quick helper function to save typing later:

```
`%|||%` <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse(length(x) == 0 | is.null(x), y, x)
}
```

Validate each list and data frame entry and put them all in one data frame:

```
lapply(json_file, function(.x) {

  for (nm in colnames(.x$data$user)) .x$data$user[,nm] <- .x$data$user[,nm] %|||% NA
  for (nm in c("score", "live_city", "live_county")) .x$data$user[,nm] <- .x$data[[nm]] %|||% NA

  .x$data$user

})
## [[1]]
##    id phone realName addr source registerDate type remain score live_city live_county
## 1 123 00001     Eric   NA     NA           NA    0     NA    NA      Nice      France
## 
## [[2]]
##    id phone realName addr source registerDate type remain score live_city live_county
## 1 456 00002      Amy   NA     NA           NA    0    100    NA        NA          NA
```